# Umbraco 7 Tiny MCE: More control over images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

Like options to set width, height, border, css class... without fiddle with source code. These could be integrated in the slide out menu that appears after clicking the media picker button ?  How can this be achieved in Umbraco 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Alex, you can create new DataType with your control. 
In admin part of Umbraco go to the 'Developer' section, 'Data Types' folder.

Comment: I know but these options are not available in Umbraco TinyMCE v3 out of the box.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do this? I want to add properties for css classes, height and width. I would also like to modify the output <img> properties and code. I can obviously view code and modify it, however I can't expect my non-technical content writers to do that.